# Substitute a reference to a method

Tags: python, python-sphinx, substitution, cross-reference

I'd like to make a table with some methods like so.

```
+-----------+------+-----+------+
| method    | prop | ref | note |
+-----------+------+-----+------+
| :meth:`m` | x    |     | sad  |
+-----------+------+-----+------+
| :func:`f` | x    | x   |      |
+-----------+------+-----+------+
```

With my real names however, the table grows quite long, particularly as I want to shorten fully qualified names with `:meth:'name <fully.qualified.name>`. I'd like to shorten the table definition by using substitutions, but I haven't found a way of making it work. Note I'm replacing backticks to avoid ending the code block early on the post. I do have them in my code. Here are some attempts.

- `.. |m| :meth:'m'` using `|m|`: Undefined substitution `'m'` referenced
- `.. _m: :meth:'m'` using `|m|_`: Undefined substitution `'m'` referenced
- `.. |m| replace:: :meth:'m'` using `|m|`: Correct text produced, but no link

How can I achieve shortening the reference? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `replace::` is indeed the answer. However, in my case Sphinx cached some information that prevented the link from being produced. After deleting the whole build folder, the links work just fine.

```
.. |m| replace:: :meth:`m`

This is |m|.
```

Comment: `make clean` will also delete the build folder, or delete just the one built file to have it rebuilt for a faster build.